# Phaser synchronizer example in Java

Tags: java, phaser

I've just read javadocs about phaser and now it's reasonobly to ask about whether the barrier implementation is applied in JDK itself (I consider `JDK7`). As the `Phaser` JavaDoc stated

> Phasers may also be used by tasks executing in a ForkJoinPool

So, I looked up Phaser's usages in the `ForkJoinPool` but I couldn't find anything. The goal is to find any real example using `Phaser`.

Comment: You misread: it is not the *implementation* of ForkJoinPool which uses Phaser, it is *tasks submitted to it* which may find Phaser convenient.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You're right .But couldn't you suggest something I could find a Phaser's usage?

Comment: Try the Streams API implementation---probably they invented Phaser for something they needed there.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Do you mean Java IO streams?

Comment: No, the Java 8 Streams API. `java.util.streams`.